# How to edit an image_tag url from Ruby File class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I have an image_tag I am trying to trim some from.

```
<%= link_to (image_tag (File.absolute_path(image))), image[/\/.*/]%>
```

It returns:

```
http://x.x.x.x/OPT/ROR/DIST_PORTAL/PUBLIC/FILES/...
```

I need to remove "/OPT/ROR/DIST_PORTAL/PUBLIC" from the image_tag url, so it has this:

```
http://x.x.x.x/FILES/...
```

How do you do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% image_path = ["/", File.dirname(image).split("/").last,"/", File.basename(image)].join('') %>
<%= link_to image_tag(image_path), image[/\/.*/]%>
```